# Program for warning sendings in LAN

Tags: lan, notifications

I work answering support chats with another 19 assistants in LAN. I'm looking for a program for Windows that allows my boss to send warnings or notifications to all of us at the same time, that also saves a record of these warnings so that anybody can see any past notification. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any specific operating system?

Comment: You might try [Slack](http://slack.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Jabber client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instant_messaging_clients#XMPP-related_features): most of them have support for chat room (sending a message to a group of people) and history. You can use a public XMPP server or run [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software) locally in your LAN if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @dmitry-grigoryev's answer, you can set up a local IRC server and use it for your private discussions. It's very easy and you can send broadcasts to all at once. Instructions on how to set up can be found online. One such link is this [one](http://www.codeography.com/2012/09/23/howto-irc-server.html).

Comment: Actually, even plain simple e-mails can be used to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the net send command.
See http://www.winsentmessenger.com/netsend/